# Incorrect syntax in SQL Server 2008R2 script containing 0x0A character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running a select statement which contains the following `CASE` clause:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE MyTable.IsBook WHEN 1 THEN  'B' ELSE  'M' END) AS IsBookOrManuscript
FROM MyTable;
```

I have the same exact database(schema and data) restored in two different physical servers running `SQL Server 2008 R2` with build version `10.50.4276.0` and SQL Server 2014 respectively.

When run in SQL Server 2014 the query returns as expected. When run in SQL Server 2008R2  the error message `Incorrect syntax near ' '.` occurs.

Searching the script file for non-ascii characters I found that indeed, three occurrences  of `0x0A` character appear in the `CASE` line and removing it solves the problem in SQL Server 2008R2.

Does anyone know why that happens? Is it an intended behavior? As far as I can see there are 2 CUs released since my last update BUT they do not seem to fix or recognize the problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are both databases running the same Collation? And the servers?

Comment: Yes both the servers and the databases are under the same collation.

Comment: As you - obviously - know, there are non printing characters. Especially line breaks can create troubles, because they are encoded differently on different systems. So the main question is not: *Does anyone know why that happens?* but *How is this script file created?* Within one document linebreaks should be consistent...

Comment: The main question is: Why is there a difference in behavior between the 2 different editions of SQL Server? The script was found and corrected by the developer that wrote it (he was copy pasting from an excel file and thus the 0x0A char).

Comment: @S.Karras The lower version is probably less tolerant... It was exactly what I thought. *Copy pasting* from different sources combines code fragments with differing line breaks... The new version can deal with this... the older can't. Maybe it's not even a problem of the Server but a problem of the version of SSMS...

Comment: Well yes, but that still does not answer why. Is it a bug that was fixed when SQL Server 2014 was released? It is not the version of the SSMS as I connect to both server with the same SSMS client.

Comment: @S.Karras just one more thought... My SSMS asks me on saving such a file if I want to use windows conform line breaks... The problem is easy to solve with simple replaces...

Comment: @S.Karras You ask *Is it a bug that was fixed when SQL Server 2014 was released* and I answer: No! It is a bug, that your file contains different lb encodings and the newer version seems to be smart enough to deal with this...

Answer (score 0):

Check the Setting  of

```
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
```

on each server.

as **MSDN** says:

> Causes SQL Server to follow the ISO rules regarding quotation mark delimiting identifiers and literal strings. Identifiers delimited by double quotation marks can be either Transact-SQL reserved keywords or can contain characters not generally allowed by the Transact-SQL syntax rules for identifiers.

so try the next code:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER off
-- Type your code here 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER On
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that is not it. The problem is not how the literals are declared but in the non-ascii characters that appear in the script.